# How to remove gap after removing axis.text?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

On this figure I removed axis.text.x by:

```
g + theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10), 
axis.text.x = element_blank()) + 
labs(x ="Percent of respondents")
```

But the gap of former axis.text.x is still there. How to remove it?

[image]

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, the space is gone when setting the text to blank.

Answer (score -1):

Solved myself:

```
align = 'h'
```

in

```
ggarrange(..., labs(x ="Percent of respondents"), 
      labels = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
      ncol = 2, nrow = 2)
```